# Removing edge lines from PolyCollection in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

[image]I'm plotting some data with a line like the following:

`poly = PolyCollection(vertices, array=s, edgecolors='w', linewidths=.0001)`

Is there a way to completely hide the edge lines around each cell? The above line attempts to do this by setting the edge colors to white and a small line width.  However, the lines still show up.  Also, passing 0 to line widths also doesn't seem to do this.

I've also tried setting `edgecolor` to `none` and `linewidth` to 0 without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can do it by setting `edgecolor='none'`

Comment: There's also `edgecolor="face"`, if `edgecolor="none"` isn't working.  On a side note, `imshow` will be much more efficient in this case.  However, if your cell spacing isn't equal, `pcolormesh`/`pcolor` are your only options.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to hide the edges. Thanks to **Ajean** for additional suggestions in the comments.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

vertices = [
    [(0.2,0.2), (0.7,0.3), (0.1, 0.6)],
    [(0.5,0.5), (0.6 ,0.8), (0.8, 0.6)]
]

poly0 = mpl.collections.PolyCollection(vertices)
poly1 = mpl.collections.PolyCollection(vertices, edgecolor="none")
poly2 = mpl.collections.PolyCollection(vertices, linewidths=0)
poly3 = mpl.collections.PolyCollection(vertices, color="blue")

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,10))
ax1.add_collection(poly0)
ax2.add_collection(poly1)
ax3.add_collection(poly2)
ax4.add_collection(poly3)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Good tip. I'll look into that a bit more. This won't necessarily work for my situation because I'm using a custom color bar so I cannot use the color argument.

Comment: @durden2.0: okay, it's very, very simple - the keyword argument is `linewidth`, not `linewidths`. Typo alarm :)

Comment: It seems like `linewidth` and `linewidths` both do the same thing to me, which doesn't hide the lines. Am I missing something?

Comment: The only difference in my example is that I'm passing an array in addition to the vertices. Maybe that is the issue..

Comment: `color` just sets both facecolor and edgecolor to be the same.  If you want to get rid of the edge color entirely, set it to 'none'.

Comment: @durden2.0, Seems to work with numpy arrays here as well. I am using `1.4.0`. Maybe a regression?
@Ajean, yes, this is a nice solution, too.

Comment: I'm using `1.4.0` and setting `edgecolor` to `none` still doesn't do it for me. Maybe it's the color bar I'm using?

Comment: @durden2.0, I would try simpifying your code step by step and see if you can find the culprit.